# RewriteRule, Proxy directive [P] - Is it possible to make request use actual proxy host?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

Does anyone know whether it is possible to make rewrite rules which use the proxying [P] directive, as shown below, to behave like `ProxyPass` used in conjunction with `ProxyPreserveHost Off`.

In other words I want the server on mydomain.net to see a request for mydomain.net not mydomain.com.

```
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$  http://mydomain.net/app1/$1 [P,L]
```

Thanks and best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [P] actually uses mod_proxy, I'd try setting ProxyPreserveHost off and seeing if that does it.

Comment: Hi! I'm using this inside a .htaccess file (shared hosting account) so I can't use server level configuaration options.
Thanks

Comment: Ah. Then no, you can't do it.

Comment: I wrote a feature request on apache httpd bugzilla tracker about that : https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53947 please support :p !